# Vector in function is returning unexpected results, loop

Tags: c++, vector

The below is expected to return the result of a match of two integers. I cannot understand why it prints some garbage numbers and also it remains in a loop.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

//given array with integers {1,3,5,5,3,3} find a pair of numbers that will equal to targetSum
//target Sum=10 for example

using namespace std;
vector<int> twoNumberSum(vector<int> array, int targetSum)
{
    unordered_set<int> nums;
    for (int num: array) {
        int potentialMatch = targetSum - num;
        if (nums.find(potentialMatch) != nums.end()) {
            vector<int> a = vector<int> {num,potentialMatch};
            vector<int> b = vector<int> {potentialMatch, num};

            return potentialMatch > num ? a : b;
        } else {
            nums.insert(num);
        }
    }

}

int main() {
    vector<int> array;
    array.push_back(1);
    array.push_back(3);
    array.push_back(5);
    array.push_back(7);
    int i;
    i = 10;
    auto res = twoNumberSum(array, i);
    for (auto item : res) 
        cout << item << endl;
}
```

Comment: Not sure, if this is what's happening, in your case (stepping through the code with a debugger, should reveal that), but: what does your function return, if `nums.find(potentialMatch) != nums.end()` is never true?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `return` statement before the end of the function. When there is no match, you'll need to return an empty vector.

```
vector<int> twoNumberSum(vector<int> array, int targetSum)
{
   unordered_set<int> nums;
   for (int num: array) {
      int potentialMatch = targetSum - num;
      if (nums.find(potentialMatch) != nums.end()) {
         vector<int> a = vector<int> {num,potentialMatch};
         vector<int> b = vector<int> {potentialMatch, num};

         return potentialMatch > num ? a : b;
      } else {
         nums.insert(num);
      }
   }

   // Missing from your code.
   return {};
}
```

Without the final `return` statement, your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: What a lesson. I was trying to assign a 'return;' and that would not be accepted since it was expecting a value in the return statement. Thank you!